# My LC tank circuit doesn't seem to work as a RF generator

Tags: rf, oscillator

I'm trying create a super simple frequency generator to create RF in a specific frequency (for sending Morse code). I have a HF SDR receiver which I use to see waterfall of frequencies.

Based on [this calculator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/tank-circuit-resonance-calculator/) this circuit is supposed to generate a RF in 14.53 MHz but when I charge up the capacitor with the switch then release it I see nothing on my waterfall. What am I doing wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2S8ot.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It will only generate a few cycles of RF. How long does the pulse need to be for it to show up on your waterfall. Does the SDR have 'dead times' that can miss a transient RF burst?

Comment: How did you build the circuit?  Did you solder wires together, or did you build it on a solderless breadboard?  Regardless, even if it works the RF burst will be very short - less than 1 millisecond for sure.

Comment: My sdr sample rate is 1.8Msps (million samples per second), that's not enough?

Comment: You've probably destroyed L1 with that circuit.

Comment: How can you destroy a coil? it's a just a piece of wire rapped in circles.

Comment: Dan, C1 *can't charge up*...L1 prevents it reaching 12V. Instead, L1 will fight with V1: L1 wants zero volts, while V1 wants 12V - a fight to death if S1 stays ON.

Comment: I have also tried charging up C1 directly then put it back in the circuit, still no luck.

Comment: _”How can you destroy a coil?”_ Short a DC voltage source with it.

Comment: But that destroys the voltage source not the coil

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how I managed to burn up and melt all those inductors way back when.

Comment: @Dan Not sure what you are hoping to see, but until crystals arrived on the scene there were very highly complex `master oscillators`. There was a point (prior to US entering WW II) where a huge debate was taking place about the new crystal concepts (and mining access to same in South America) competing with `master oscillators`. My point is that if you need a precision RF frequency and expect to use an LC then also expect a lot of difficulties getting theory into practice. It was a continual and unresolved problem prior to crystals or crystal-derived systems.

Comment: @Dan See *"Crystal Clear: The Struggle for Reliable Communications Technology in World War II"* by Richard J. Thompson for more historical details.

Answer (score 2):

These basic experiments *can work* in principle, but are often frustrated by the details of implementation.

OP's circuit can provide enough antenna signal for a nearby receiver, provided S1 opens and closes fast enough - a hand-operated switch is probably too slow. If S1 opens and closes 14,530,000 times per second, *something* should be heard on a nearby receiver.
The circuit may need tweaking - the antenna will tend to add some reactive impedance to L1, C1 that de-tunes resonance.

Since few switches can open and close fast enough, a transistor switch would be used instead. A logic gate could provide excitation too, through a resistor that protects it from over-voltage and over-current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKRJUF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just like OP's conceptual circuit, regard these as conceptual circuits. V1, V2 ideally represent pulse generators providing pulses at 14.53 MHz rate to drive the resonant circuits: **Q1** similar to a SPST switch, and **NOT1** would drive R2 with a logic waveform pulsing at 14.56 MHz.
These generators could also operate at a subharmonic: (7.265MHz, 4.8433MHz, 2.906MHz...)